# What is the most efficient way of doing this coordinate transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m trying to do a coordinate transformation from a reference frame with basis (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) to a molecular frame. All I have are the (x,y,z) positions of all of the molecules according to the original reference frame, and wish to obtain the positions in the molecular frame such that the center of mass of each molecule is centered at the origin in its new frame. How do I do that?

---

EDIT: I think this problem becomes: given the positions in the laboratory reference frame, how do I find the 3 x 3 rotation matrix to transfer to the local reference frame? Does knowing the positions of the atoms in each molecule help at all?

Comment: Is the molecular frame already constructed or are you looking for how to construct an appropriate rotation? The translation component is trivial.

Comment: Subtract the center of mass coordinates from the coordinates of each molecule. This is a translation of coordinates which moves the center of mass to the origin. Did you try  that?

Comment: @amd I'm looking how to construct an appropriate rotation. As for the other comment, the reason I want to do a coordinate transformation is because I then need to calculate a distance with respect to the center of mass, which I think seems necessary to do in the molecular frame, not the initial reference frame.

Comment: Do I need to construct a 3 x 3 rotation matrix and find the Euler angles? If so, how do I do that? Or, is there a simpler way?

Comment: Distances are invariant under both translation and rotation (which is part of why both are called "rigid motions"). So you can compute the distance in either coordinate frame and get the same answer.

Comment: Can we see an example of an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a molecule whose center of mass has coordinates $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ in the laboratory frame, then a transformation of coordinates that puts the molecule's center of mass at the origin of its own coordinate system is

$$ (x, y, z) \to (x - x_1, y - y_1, z - z_1).$$

This is the simplest transformation that puts the molecule at its own origin of coordinates, but **this is not a rotation.** 
There is no $3\times 3$ matrix that will transform coordinates in this way.
In fact there is no $3\times 3$ matrix that will do what you asked.
Matrices, Euler angles, and so forth are for **rotation around the origin,**
which means that the origin stays where it was,
so anything that had coordinates $(0,0,0)$ before the rotation still has coordinates $(0,0,0)$ afterward, and anything that didn't have coordinates $(0,0,0)$ still doesn't have coordinates $(0,0,0).$

I question whether you want to do **any** transformation of coordinates, however.
If you put every molecule at the center of its own coordinate system,
then things expressed in one molecule's coordinates don't immediately tell you about how those things relate to another molecule's coordinates.
You would have to be continually transforming things between coordinates in order to relate the different pieces of data to each other.
Unless there is a compelling reason why a particular frame of reference would be better than the laboratory frame, I would urge you to reconsider whether you need another frame of reference. It is likely that whatever you're trying to do, it is just as easy to compute in the laboratory frame as any other way.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up some things. Obviously, (x1,y1,z3) are the coordinates of the center of mass in the laboratory frame, but what are (x,y,z)? How do I find those? The reason I want to transform coordinates is because I then want to calculate some distance with respect to the center of mass of each molecule.

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ are the coordinates of anything you want. Or of an empty point in space. The rule for the transformation tells you how to get the coordinates of the same thing relative to the molecule at $(x_1,y_1,z_1).$

Comment: If you choose _any_ Cartesian coordinate system, if you have one thing $A$ with coordinates $(x_A,y_A,z_A)$ and another thing $B$ with coordinates $(x_B,y_B,z_B)$, the distance between them is $\sqrt{(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2+(z_A-z_B)^2}.$ No transformation required. If you _do_ transform to a coordinate frame where $B$ is at the origin, you can just square the new coordinates of $A$ instead of the differences of coordinates, but you had to compute the differences in order to get the new coordinates, so you might not even be saving any calculation.

Comment: Thanks. One other question: I do the coordinate transformation you suggested, then calculate a site on the rigid body with respect to the center of mass at the origin, and wish to transfer back to the original laboratory frame to check the distance between the sites on different molecules. I do the back transformation by adding the original center-of-mass value. But that just makes the distances that I calculate equal to the center-of-mass distances. How do I take the distances between the sites that I calculate?

Comment: "But that just makes the distances that I calculate equal to the center-of-mass distances." What is a "center-of-mass distance"? A distance must be between something and something else. What is the first "something"? What is the "something else"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the distance between centers of mass on different molecules. I think I figured it out. Thanks for all of your help! I'll vote your answer as the top answer.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of the calculations you're able to do!

Comment: @defarm What kind of calculations do you want to see, and from whom? I already have a coordinate transformation by translation (in the answer) and distance between two points (in a comment). I would have been interested in seeing more specific examples in the question, but if that's what you meant then a comment under the question would be clearer.

Comment: @DavidK I meant that as well.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, each molecule is not a point, but some volume around a point. My first thought is that you can calculate a vector from the center of mass with some angle theta and another angle phi (think spherical coordinates) with a magnitude the length of the radius. You then use that point as one of these sites. Assuming there's some other molecule at the origin, you can do the same procedure and then find the distance between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are working within $\mathbb{R}^3$, we are working with a finite dimensional vector space. We have two ordered bases, $\beta$ and $\beta '$ which both span $\mathbb{R}^3$. By convention, we say that the 'old basis' is $\beta '$ and the 'new basis' is $\beta$. We can to find some change of coordinate matrix $Q$ which changes $\beta '$ coordinates into $\beta$ coordinates. It is a fact that the following equations hold:

$$[T]_{\beta '} = Q^{-1}[T]_\beta Q \text{ and } [T]_{\beta} = Q[T]_{\beta '}Q^{-1}$$

Since the old basis is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the new basis is some other basis which spans $\mathbb{R}^3$, the only step left is to find out what $Q$ and its inverse are. To find $Q$, you set up the augmented matrix $[\beta | \beta ']$ and, through elementary row operations, get to reduced row echelon form. This can be seen in the following example:

$\beta ' = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\} = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\} \\
\beta = \{(1,0,2),(-2,0,-1),(0,1,0)\} \\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}1&0&0&1&-2&0\\0&1&0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&2&-1&0\end{array}\right]$

Since the augmented matrix is already in RREF, we can see that $Q$ is the same as $\beta$. To find $Q^{-1}$ rewrite an augmented matrix in the form $[\beta ' | \beta]$.

I think this may answer your question, or at least a part of it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the new basis for my system?

Comment: Ah. That's up to you. I'm not sure where your missing basis is because that depends on what the transformation does. The new basis will depend entirely on what the linear operator _actually_ does to your old basis.